# Issue with Python swagger-client for Shopware 6 - Empty Data in Responses

Tags: shopware6

I have generated a Python client using the swagger-codegen-cli (v3) Docker image in my GitLab CI pipeline for a Shopware 6 shop. The problem I am encountering is that every endpoint I call returns empty data. The puzzling part is that during debugging, I can see the data in the response via the inspector. However, just before the data is returned, it attempts to deserialize the data, resulting in a dictionary with no data inside:

```py
 return_data = response_data
 if _preload_content:
 # deserialize response data
 if response_type:
 return_data = self.deserialize(response_data, response_type)
```

This snippet is from the __call_api() function. When I inspect response_data, I can see that it contains the required data, but deserialize() returns this: {'data': None, 'included': None, 'links': None, 'meta': None}. I've considered setting the parameter _preload_content to false, but this would return the raw request response as a byte string, which defeats the purpose of using a Swagger client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider exploring OpenAPI Generator, as several prominent contributors who were previously involved with Swagger Codegen have transitioned to OpenAPI Generator. It's worth noting that the Python client generator has undergone significant improvements in the 5.x releases.

[Link](https://openapi-generator.tech)